# Curvature of the total space of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\to X$ be a Hermitian holomorphic vector bundle over a Kahler manifold and denote by $Y$ the total space of $E$ as a complex manifold. What would be the connection (and curvature) of $Y$ in terms of the connections (and curvatures) of $X$ and $E$?

Comment: There is no canonical connection/metric on $Y$. What choice do you make?

Comment: @MoisheKohan there is a canonical connection on $E$ (the Chern one) which should induce a connection on $Y$.

Comment: "Should induce"? How?

Comment: You might be interested in Calabi's "Métriques kählériennes et fibrés holomorphes", where he constructs a metric on the total space of a holomorphic vector bundle and calculates its curvature: http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1979_4_12_2_269_0.pdf

Comment: @TedShifrin well the Chern connection on $E$ gives us a splitting $TY=TE\simeq TX\oplus E$. Since we have a metric both on $TX$ and $E$ we can decide that they are orthogonal and obtain a metric on $TY$. Given that $Y$ is a complex manifold there is a Chern connection on the $TY$.

Comment: To answer my question the following paper treats that question: *Finsler geometry of projectivized vector bundles* By J.-G. Cao and Pit-Mann Wong